# Regex Match string from starts with

Tags: c#, regex, string, match

this is my Regular expression.

```
^AK[0-9A-Za-z-/#\s]{1,15}$
```

It matches the **whole string** when we enter some text which starts like'AKtest123'

but i want to match the below strings like

```
A
AK
AKtest
```

how can i modify the regex to match the string from the first character?

Comment: How about ^A[0-9A-Za-z-/#\s]{0,15}$

Comment: not clear what you are asking. do you want all words starting with `A`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the magic:

```
^(A|AK[0-9A-Za-z-/#\s]{0,15})$
```

That means it will accept A, or AK (notice I changed 1 at the end to 0), or AK and any following 15 characters from the list. Is that what you want, right?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're looking for something like this?

```
^A(?:K(?:[0-9A-Za-z-/#\s]{1,15})?)?$
```

It will match:

```
A
AK
AKtest
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need groups.

Change your regex to:

```
^(((A)K)[0-9A-Za-z-/#\s]{1,15})$
```

Group1 will have `A`, Group2 will have `AK` and Group3 will have `AKtest`